# Possible to programatically create sync profile on Windows live mesh 2011

Tags: windows-live

I'm creating application in c#. My customer need to sync program settings on windows live. I need to create windows live mesh profile like "Internet explorer favorites"

I'm can not found any developer tool and help.

Is it possible?